# Why can't I use Override annotation?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, overriding

I have a class that extends another class:

```
public class PDFCrawler extends WebCrawler
```

And I am overriding a method in my PDFCrawler class as follows:

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldVisit(Page page, WebURL url) {...}
```

It gives me error on Eclipse. Java 8 is set for the project:

> The method shouldVisit(Page, WebURL) of type PDFCrawler must override
>   or implement supertype method.

However, in the same PDFCrawler class, when I am overriding a different method as follows, no error is shown:

```
@Override
    public void visit(Page page) {...}
```

Both of these methods are from the super class named WebCrawler. The superclass methods are as follows:

```
public boolean shouldVisit(Page page, WebURL url) {
    return true;
  }

public void visit(Page page) {
    // Do nothing by default
    // Sub-classed should override this to add their custom functionality
  }
```

The superclass is taken from [Crawler4j project](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/WebCrawler.java). As I cannot override the first method, the method in the superclass is always getting executed.

Any clue?

**EDIT**
The import statements for my class PDFCrawler:

```
package com.example.ict;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.google.common.io.Files;

import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Page;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler;
import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL;
```

Comment: Same `Page` type? Same `WebURL` type?

Comment: Maybe you are using `WebURL` from a different package..

Comment: Hi @SotiriosDelimanolis The arguments of my methods and the superclass methods are the same. Even I kept the data type and name the same as in the superclass

Comment: They might have the same _name_, but are they the same **type**?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: that's not necessary, the *Liskov substitution principle* allows to narrow return types and widen parameter types. But the OP should better provide a MWE.

Comment: @CommuSoft I think you misunderstand. `WebCrawler` declares a `shouldVisit` method with parameters of type `edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.Page` and `edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL`. If OP has a `com.example.Page` type in the same package as `PDFCrawler`, then that `Page` type will be used when compiling `PDFCrawler`.

Comment: What @SotiriosDelimanolis is saying is to look at the imports for your classes, and see if the WebUrl import statement is the same for both PDFCrawler and WebCrawler

Comment: @CommuSoft Also, I don't believe you can widen parameter types in Java.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: not in Java indeed, since it does not fully implement the *lsp*, and because it could generate conflicts between two generations. From a type-theory perspective however, one can allow this.

Comment: I am using the jar provided in the crawler package. So what needs to be done to override the methods?

Comment: Add all of your `import` statements to the question so that we can verify the package of the parameters.

Comment: @erickson, I have edited the question and gave the parameters.

Comment: Thank you. That eliminates the suggestion that you have another type with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you're using the jar file from an older version of crawler4j. The signature of this method was different in the past and was changed without support for backward compatibility (unfortunately): https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/commit/c874761011d63e77977b914810eb44c054845233

Using the latest version of the jar should fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @Yasser thanks for the answer. I am using its version 3.5.

Comment: It was a version mismatch problem. v4.1 works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

PDFCrawler.shouldVisit method is using different parameter types. Most probably the types are from a different package.

Answer (score 0):

Your import for `WebURL` is wrong, this will work:

```
public boolean shouldVisit(Page page, edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL url) {...}
```

`Page` as you used it in other `@Override`, is OK, but not `WebURL`, so better fix the imports!

Comment: Hi @Jordi, I already have imported edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.url.WebURL and my error is after importing it.